# Provide a method to search for sites

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stackauth, api-v1.1

Due to the new pagination of the [/sites](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/stackauth-methods/sites) method in [v1.1](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/stack-exchange-api-1-1-and-improved-app-gallery/) of the API, we have to go through all the pages of sites to check whether a site exists, or allow the user to search for a site.

Would it be possible to provide a way to search the list instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination on /sites is solely so [app]s don't have to pull down any unknown, large, and constantly growing chunk of a data in a single request.

It is expected that every consumer would grab all sites in a series of sequential (or concurrent, if they're comfortable with that) requests for each page.

Comment: Well please keep the 1.0 version, during 2.0 and beyond. The pagination makes no sense. When would an app only show one page of sites? you say that you'd expect every consumer would make multiple requests? Surely it's better to avoid the multiple requests?

Answer (score 6):

For now, as we have only ~80 sites, you can set `pagesize` to 100 and get them all.

But in general, I think pagination here makes no sense at all. Because there're no search parameters or ordering, I can't think of a situation where app can fetch only first page and be satisfied.

*Would it be possible to provide a way to search the list instead?*
I would propose just getting the whole list of sites, caching it (as documentation recommends) and searching locally.

Comment: +1 I really don't see the benefit of pagination on the `/sites` results.  I'm never going to want only *some* of the sites; I want all or nothing.

Comment: Same I think pagination is a waste of bandwidth, in that it adds a few lines at the top, also it wastes effort.

Comment: What I've done is create a `cron` script that runs every 24 hours, polls `/sites`, and sticks the results into a MySQL database. That way I can search, re-order, and do all manner of things with it.

Comment: @George; but how does that affect the pagination? The script still has to multiple requests (at least it will do when there's more than 100 sites, and if you take a look at Area 51 that's going to happen pretty soon)

Comment: Can this be put into feature-request?

Comment: @Jonathan: Well, just issue enough requests to get all of the sites **or** use v1.0 of the API, which returns all of them no matter how many there are.

Comment: @George: it seems one of the points in 1.1 was to reduce the amount of traffic, so making you do more requests, increases the traffic and makes it more complicated. And while 1.0 is around now, when 2.0 is available the style of 1.1 is more than likely going to be used. It's easier to get it changed when it's new.

Comment: @Jonathan: True. This is important because it affects me too.

Comment: @George: I didn't say that it didn't affect you??

Comment: @Jonathan: It does affect me - and it affects you too. I'm just saying that in the meantime, I have a method for dealing with this.