# How to search ALL sites with the advanced API?

Tags: api, api-v2.2, search, support

I can make a request to Stack Overflow as follows, which searches with keywords in titles:

[/2.2/search/advanced?title=vlookup%20index%20match&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=creation&title=vlookup%20index%20match&site=stackoverflow)

My question is whether there is way to make such a search cross all the sites of Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no easy way to do this via the API.

Related feature requests:

1. *[Provide a method to search for sites](https://stackapps.com/questions/2006/provide-a-method-to-search-for-sites)* winch merely wanted a search for site name/description.  It was **declined**.
2. [*Search across Stack Exchange sites in Android app*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246267/search-across-stack-exchange-sites-in-android-app).  To implement this usually would mean that a supporting method would be added to the API.  This feature-request has been **ignored**.

**Your alternatives are:**

1. **Scrape** the Stack Exchange network search results page, EG [stackexchange.com/search?q=foo](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=foo)
2. **Loop** through `/2.2/search/advanced` for each site and aggregate the results.
3. Use some **third-party search** API, like [the *DuckDuckGo Instant Answer API*](https://duckduckgo.com/api).